# constructor in inheritance in java

Tags: java

```
public class Conininher {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
        Ba obj1=new Ba();
      }
}

class Aa{
    public Aa(){
        this(10);
        System.out.println("hello");
    }
    public Aa(int x){
        System.out.println("hw r u");
    }
}

class Ba extends Aa{
    public Ba(){
        this(5);
        System.out.println("hii");
    }
    public Ba(int x){
        System.out.println("bye");
    }
}
```

Why isn't the this(10) in Aa not working? when the object of class Ba is created, at first the default constructor of Ba is called which in turn calls the default constructor of Aa, which calls the parameterised constructor of Aa. so, I was expecting the output to be
    hello, hw r u, hii , bye.

Comment: And which output do you get instead of the expected one?

Comment: according to my knowledge out put would be  hw r u, hello, bye,hii

Answer (score 3):

Why did you expect "hello" to be printed before "hw r u"?

```
public Aa()
{
    this(10);
    System.out.println("hello");
}
```

calls

```
public Aa(int x)
{
    System.out.println("hw r u");
}
```

so "hw r u" is printed first, and only afterwards "hello" is printed.

Similarly, "bye" is printed before "hii", since

```
public Ba()
{
    this(5);
    System.out.println("hii");

}
```

calls

```
public Ba(int x)
{
    System.out.println("bye");
}
```

which prints "bye", and only after it returns, "hii" is printed.

To summarize:

```
Ba obj1=new Ba();
```

calls

```
public Ba()
```

which calls

```
public Ba(int x)
```

which calls

```
public Aa()
```

which calls

```
public Aa(int x)
```

which prints "hw r u"

then public Aa() prints "hello"

then public Ba(int x) prints "bye"

finally public Ba() prints "hii"

Comment: yeah that's what i actually meant(hw r u,hello,bye,hii).  But the output I am getting in eclipse is only three statements, i.e the output I am getting  is  hello , hii , bye no  hw r u.

Comment: @ravikiran I ran the code and got all 4 Strings in the order I mentioned.

Comment: Thanks ,it's the fault of eclipse.I got it right in cmd. But why?

Answer (score 1):

If the first line of a constructor call isn't a `super()` or `this()`, then a `super()` is inserted. For your desired output, you need something like

```
class Aa {
    public Aa() {
        System.out.println("hello");
    }

    public Aa(int x) {
        this();
        System.out.println("hw r u");
    }
}

class Ba extends Aa {
    public Ba() {
        this(5);
        System.out.println("bye");
    }

    public Ba(int x) {
        super(x);
        System.out.println("hii");
    }
}
```

Which I ran and got (as requested)

```
hello
hw r u
hii
bye
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought too.But I am not getting "hw r u" in eclipse. only three statements are being printed .And they are in the correct order. output is hello, bye ,hii.  why no "hw r u".